# Trouble with sliding textarea

Tags: html, css, textarea

Help me please with sliding textarea. If i add icon of wrong field, my textarea goes left. Some screenshots: 
[image: screen1] [image: scrren2]

And some code:

```
<div class="signup">
 <center>
    <h1>Форма регистрации</h1>
    <p>Для получения информации и участия в акциях информация должна быть правдивой</p>


    <form name="registerform">
        <p>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Ваше имя" id="user_login" class="input" size="20" /> <span id="user_login_result"></span>
        </p>

        <p>
            <input type="email" placeholder="Ваш Email" id="user_email" class="input" size="20" /> <span id="user_email_result"></span>
        </p>
   </form>

 </center>
</div>
```

css:

```
#user_login.input, #user_email.input {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    width: 50%;
    border-radius: 0;
}
```

code when icon shows:

```
<p>
 <input type="text" placeholder="Ваше имя" id="user_login" class="input" size="20" /> <span id="user_login_result"><img src="un-available.png" /></span>
</p>
```

Comment: Please add CSS as well with your HTML.

Comment: Also please show code for both with and without the icon in as well!

Comment: provide a fiddle and help us to reproduce the issue to fix it .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<center>` tags are obsolete - you should use margin-left and margin right instead

here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RachGal/oypgd4mz/1/)

```css
.signup {
  width: 100%;
}
#user_login.input,
#user_email.input {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  width: 50%;
  border-radius: 0;
}
h1,
.text {
  text-align: center;
}
form {
  margin-left: 24%;
  margin-right: 24%, text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="signup">

  <h1>Форма регистрации</h1>
  <p class="text">Для получения информации и участия в акциях информация должна быть правдивой</p>


  <form name="registerform">
    <p>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Ваше имя" id="user_login" class="input" size="20" /> <span id="user_login_result"><img src="http://www.iberia.com/ibcomv3/rbrand/img/content/ico-x.gif" width="10px" height="10px"></span>
    </p>

    <p>
      <input type="email" placeholder="Ваш Email" id="user_email" class="input" size="20" /> <span id="user_email_result"></span>
    </p>
  </form>


</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ofcourse your element will move to left because when you put your image, the new element needs some space for its own existence. Hence CSS pushes your input element to left to make some room.

A straight forward answer is that you need to pre-define where your elements will appear and have the space reserved for them. One way is to convert your form into a table and make your table fixed and assign width to each cell. Sample below.

Since you did not provide us with CSS, I made a sample [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/L3L13pez/) that might not look exactly like yours but its close.

You will notice that:
When you click the input box, a new element with some text "icon" appears, but it does not move the element to the left. Instead it takes space from right.

So what have I done here:

## HTML

```
<div class="signup">
 <center>
    <h1>Форма регистрации</h1>
    <p>Для получения информации и участия в акциях информация должна быть правдивой</p>

    <table>
    <form name="registerform">
        <p>
            <tr><td>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Ваше имя" id="user_login" class="input first" size="20" /> <span id="user_login_result"></span>
                </td></tr>
        </p>

        <p>
            <tr><td>
            <input type="email" placeholder="Ваш Email" id="user_email" class="input first" size="20" /> <span id="user_email_result"></span>
                 </td></tr>
        </p>
   </form>
     </table>

 </center>
</div>
```

## CSS

```
table {
        table-layout: fixed;
        width: 200px;
}

table .first {
    width: 60%;
    display: inline-block;
}

table .second {
    width: 20%;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

I have made your form into a table and have given it a width that it cannot exceed. I have also told the elements that they can only take 'x' amount of space and do not touch the other one.

Don't worry about the javascript. Its just there to dynamically put the "image" element as soon as you focus on the input element.